# excel Blank on the right side of graph

Tags: excel, graph

I was looking for a similar problems, but couldn't find an answer to this issue. I have a huge blank space on the side of my graph. 
I cant change the axis setting because my graph auto updates when new data is entered. I have also cleaned the table, so there is no empty data in the table.

my graph
[image]

[image]

Comment: Select the graph, click right button and choose "select data" from the menu. What is the range?

Comment: i had to make sure no empty cells were part of any of the ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means your Axis labels or Series values are derived by a formula. In order to deal with the scenario, create two dynamic named ranges and use them as series for the chart.

Assuming your axis labels are in column B, create a named range using the formula given below...

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B:$B,"?*")-1)
```

Same way create another named range to hold the series values.

And then right click the chart --> choose Select Data --> select the series and the axis label one by one --> Edit --> And in the series values or in the axis label range, use the relevant named range using the formula given below..

```
Sheet1!YourNameRangeForAxisLabel

Sheet1!YourNameRangeForSeriesValues
```

Here Sheet1 is the sheet which the named ranges belong to.

Later this would be changed automatically and reflect the workbook reference correctly.

Comment: Hi, thats what I did. I just uploaded a image showing my formulas.

Comment: Subtract 1 to exclude Available minutes like this... =OFFSET(Sum!$B$3,,,1,COUNTA(Sum!$3:$3)-1)

Comment: Or if headers are text only (no formulas), you can refer Row1 in the offset formula for all the named ranges like  =OFFSET(Sum!$B$3,,,1,COUNTA(Sum!$1:$1)-1) and just change the B3 as per the named range.